# Getting JNA to work with SCO

Tags: java, jna

I have a very basic JNA test setup that I want to use to verify whether or not I can use JNA with Java 1.4 on SCO.  Yes, this is very much a legacy project.  No, I'm required to use these technologies.  I've already verified that Java 1.4 is capable of supporting JNA by running it on a local Windows machine, however, when I move things over to a SCO VM I have setup and try to run it there, I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError:

jnidispatch (/com/sun/jna/openserver-ia32/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path

I can't seem to find a place where I can download this.  I figured it might be bundled into the platform.jar on JNA's github, but alas not.  So where can I get this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look inside the jna.jar, you can see the platforms they support (by default):

darwin
freebsd-amd64
freebsd-i386
linux-amd64
linux-arm
linux-i386
linux-ia64
linux-ppc
linux-ppc64
sunos-amd64
sunos-sparc
sunos-sparcv9
sunos-x86
w32ce-arm
win32-amd64
win32-x86

looks like you need to build your own for SCO (it uses ant, shouldn't be that hard).