# Some problems with JNI Android studio and com.sun.jna

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, jna

I am a beginner in *Android* programming. My first task is porting an **iOS-app** to **Android** via *Android studio*.

> To solve the problem I have to use our **.so** library written on **c++**. There are a method that takes as input the next parameter: char ** data.(e.g. `bool get_some(char ** data)` ).

I have read about PointerByReference, provided by jna. I installed jna via dependencies -> add-> library dependence (I have also tried to add jna in another ways).

> The main problem is: I can use classes from jna (Android studio successfully imports packages into code), but my app crashes when I try to use something from these packages.

For example, app with string like `PointerByReference pointer = new PointerByReference();` will crash with the report:

```
jnidispatch (/com/sun/jna/linux-amd64/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path".
```

(I tried run my app on genymotion emulator)

The `/com/sun/jna/linux-amd64/libjnidispatch.so` exists in jar-file!

I have studied this

[getting-jna-to-work-with-sco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406343/getting-jna-to-work-with-sco)

[exception-in-thread-main-Java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-jnidispatch-com-sun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346438/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-jnidispatch-com-sun).

But I can't solve the problem! By the way, working with Eclipse, I do not have such problem. He downloaded libjnidispatch.dll from jar-file.

To conclude. How to avoid/fix the problem?

My OS is windows 10, Android studio, SDK are latest version.

Comment: If your code is C++, you probably want to try out other solutions than JNA...

Comment: @Samuel Audet I selected JNA because on desktop version of the ios-app `ref IntPtr` instead char** has been used. So, what could you advice me to use instead JNA?

Comment: What does your Java code need to do?  What's the output from `bool get_some( char **data )`?  Without knowing that, it's not easy to propose solutions.

Comment: `char**` usually means an array of C strings (in memory, several consecutive pointers).  It _sometimes_ means the called function will write a pointer of type `char*` at the memory location provided.  If the former, you can pass in Java `String[]`.

Comment: When deploying to Android, you need to follow the instructions for deploying a native shared library with your app.  You won't be able to dynamically unpack it from a jar file, it has special installation requirements.

Comment: @AndreySamoilov I provide a little list here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp#introduction